# Why am I getting unicodeand large numbers when reading from binary text?

Tags: c++, c, list, binary, fstream

I am reading a list using ifstream from a binary file to build an array. Here is my build array function:

```
    int buildArrays (Player players[])
{

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open( "binary_hockey", ios::binary );

if ( inFile.fail() )
   {
   cout << "The binary_hockey input file did not open";
   return 0;
   }


Player onePlayer;
int index = 1;

inFile.read( (char *) &onePlayer, sizeof(Player) );

while (inFile)
{
    index++;
    inFile.read( (char *) &onePlayer, sizeof(Player) );
}

inFile.close();
return index-1;

}
```

And then I am using this function to print the array on the screen.

```
void printArrays( Player players[], int numPlayers)
{

    int i = 0;
    int pnts;

while((i)<numPlayers)     //keeps displaying the info as long as num players is greater the array building up t
        {

    pnts = players[i].goals + players[i].assists;

    cout<<left<<setw(20)<<players[i].name<<setw(10)<<players[i].goals<<setw(10)<<players[i].assists<<setw(10)<<pnts << endl;

    i++;
        }

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
}
```

The result is that I am getting unicode characters and very large numbers rather than names and single digit numbers from the binary list. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is the file created?  Perhaps in a mode different from `ios::binary`?  Is the number of players correct?  It would be interesting to know what happens if the file has a single player.

Comment: Also: do tag this "c++" to help people find it.

Comment: can you post more code, like the player class and the generation of players?

Comment: I solved it. Was feeding it into the wrong array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading into `players`. Your code should look like:

```
while (inFile)
{
 inFile.read( (char *) &players[index++], sizeof(Player) );
}
```

Comment: whenever I try that I get the following errors: Player players shadows a parameter and no match for operator[] in players[index++]